# How to remove decoration of an <a> tag

Tags: css, html, web

I have an **a** tag and a **li** inside it. The **a** tag colors the list items innterText. How can I nullify its effects on the color of its content and also remove the underline?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <a href="google.com"><li>asd</li></a>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your code, or better yet, create a snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is invalid to have `<a>` inside `<ul>` tag in the way you did, and it's also won't pass the [W3C validation](https://validator.w3.org/). However, If I understand your question, you may try this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <ul>
                <li>asd</li>
            </ul>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In order to remove the underline, you can do:

```
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #b61c1c; /* For Example */
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/parusevose/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1):

You can style it like this:

```
<a style="text-decoration: none; color: #TheColorYouWant"></a>
```

Comment: That won't remove the color applied

Comment: @DarrenSweeney yep, i forget about the color. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a {
       background-color: transparent;
    }

 a:hover {
       text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS. this removes underlines from a and li elements:

```
a, li {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your style according to your requirements inside this class "a:-webkit-any-link". for example if you want to remove underline then just add "a:-webkit-any-link{text-decoration: none;}".
Note: Here we are using '-webkit-' for Chrome browser.

Comment: You might want to format your code samples using markdown- read about it [in the help section for markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solution to remove all the default styling from an  tag is

```
a {unset:all}
```